# Are all torsion groups finite groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Are all torsion groups finite groups?

I've been trying to find a counter example, but have had no luck so far. Can anyone throw me one, or give me an idea to prove this?

Comment: An infinite direct sum of finite abelian groups is a wide example. For a tall example, pick $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ for instance.

Comment: @whacka Whats the difference between a tall and wide example?

Comment: I am using the adjectives figuratively. More precisely both examples are both tall and wide, but the primary components $\Bbb Z[1/p]/\Bbb Z$ are each tall and standing straight up. (One can see the relevance of the terms by looking at the lattice of subgroups.)

Comment: @whacka Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take infinite direct sum of finite abelian groups. For finitely generated examples google "Burnside problem".

If you do not know what is the direct sum of groups, take the group of roots of unity:
$$
\{ e^{i\pi r}: r\in {\mathbb Q}\}.  
$$

Comment: The Grigorchuk group is an example of a fintiely generated infinite torsion group that is relatively easy to understand.

Comment: We havent gone over this material yet, are there any more elementary examples? If not I will set out to understand this one.

Comment: @Raylan: Did you cover direct sums of vector spaces in your linear algebra class? Then think about the one-dimensional vector space ${\mathbb Z}_2$ and take its direct sum with itself infinitely many times. Now, think of this example as an additive group.

Comment: @studiosus We did, it needed some time to fall into place as I took linear algebra in another language. Thank you for both examples.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, how about $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Yeah, you're right.